# Find Element in Tree Given a List of Directions

Tags: haskell

Looking at [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers#taking-a-walk), I implemented a function that, given a binary tree, i.e. left and right branches, give a list of `Directions` and give the element at that location.

Here's the `Tree`:

`data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)`

And then the functions:

```
elemAt :: Directions -> Tree a -> a  
elemAt []     (Node x _ _) = x
elemAt (R:ds) (Node _ _ r) = elemAt ds r
elemAt (L:ds) (Node _ l _) = elemAt ds l
```

But, I re-wrote it to be safe (maybe not)

```
maybeElemAt :: Directions -> Tree a -> Maybe a  
maybeElemAt []     (Node x _ _)     = Just x
maybeElemAt (R:ds) (Node _ _ Empty) = Nothing
maybeElemAt (R:ds) (Node _ _ r)     = maybeElemAt ds r
maybeElemAt (L:ds) (Node _ Empty _) = Nothing
maybeElemAt (L:ds) (Node _ l _)     = maybeElemAt ds l
```

**Testing**

```
anotherTree :: Tree Char
anotherTree = Node 'A' (Node 'B' Empty Empty) Empty

ghci> maybeElemAt [R,R,R] anotherTree
Nothing
ghci> maybeElemAt [R] anotherTree
Nothing
ghci> maybeElemAt [L] anotherTree
Just 'B'
```

Please critique my implementations of either function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that safe.

```
*Main> maybeElemAt [] Empty
*** Exception: tree.hs:(7,1)-(11,54): Non-exhaustive patterns in function maybeElemAt
```

So let's add a pattern

```
maybeElemAt :: Directions -> Tree a -> Maybe a  
maybeElemAt []     (Node x _ _)     = Just x
maybeElemAt (R:ds) (Node _ _ Empty) = Nothing
maybeElemAt (R:ds) (Node _ _ r)     = maybeElemAt ds r
maybeElemAt (L:ds) (Node _ Empty _) = Nothing
maybeElemAt (L:ds) (Node _ l _)     = maybeElemAt ds l
maybeElemAt _ Empty = Nothing
```

And now we can see that two of the patterns can be removed:

```
maybeElemAt []     (Node x _ _) = Just x
maybeElemAt (R:ds) (Node _ _ r) = maybeElemAt ds r
maybeElemAt (L:ds) (Node _ l _) = maybeElemAt ds l
maybeElemAt _ Empty = Nothing
```

GHC has an option `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`, or you can use `-W` to get that plus other warnings. See [Warnings and sanity-checking](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html) in the GHC User's Guide.